# How to get super table information in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My database had a lot of parent and child tables.The tables contains the foreign key which has the link with the parent table.I wants to get the information of parent table of the child table using java?How can I achieve that?

```
For ex,consider the student and mark table,
The student table contains the information like studentID,name.
studentID-Primary key
The marks table contains the markId,studentId,Sub1,sub2,sub3 etc
markId-Primarykey
studentID-Foreignkey refers Student table
```

My table creation queries are,

```
CREATE TABLE `Student12` (
  `studentId` SMALLINT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentId`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `Marks` (
  `markId` SMALLINT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject1` SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
  `subject2` SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
  `studentId` SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`markId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Marks_Student` FOREIGN KEY `FK_Marks_Student` (`studentId`)
    REFERENCES `Student12` (`studentId`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If I give the mark table name as input, how can I get its parent or super table name student and information about student table?Any help should be appreciable.

Comment: You can retrieve all of these from `information_schema` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the way tables are created. Foreign keys are not mandatory to create, they could be a simple column in one table with no explicit relationship to the other table. If you are very sure that the links are created explicitly (the `foreign keys` are defined) then you could use `information_schema`. But if there is no `foreign key` defined (which is true in most of the databases I have seen), then there is no way for you to find the links inside the database. You have to look into the code (if there is any available) and try to find a clue.

Comment: Hi Jermin,I have the foreign keys in my table,How can i get the supertable name using information scema?I have refer the information schema's table_constrainits,but i can't find out the way to get super table informations?Is there any other way?

Comment: The table you need to look at is `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`. All the information you need is there. Something like: `select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'marks'`

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC DatasetMetaData interface provides a couple of methods that may help.  (The following text is copied from the javadoc.

- [`ResultSet getExportedKeys(String catalog, String schema, String table)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
  Retrieves a description of the foreign key columns that reference the given table's primary key columns (the foreign keys exported by a table).
- [`ResultSet getCrossReference(String parentCatalog, String parentSchema, String parentTable, String foreignCatalog, String foreignSchema, String foreignTable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCrossReference%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
  Retrieves a description of the foreign key columns in the given foreign key table that reference the primary key or the columns representing a unique constraint of the parent table (could be the same or a different table).

Of course, these can only work if the relevant columns have been declared as foreign keys in the SQL table DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to retrieve informations about foreign keyes
and the referenced Tables. Im not sure if it works with all kinds of MySql Tables.
The principle is to use the follwing code (not tested) to retrieve information about the super tables

```
ResultSet rs = null;
DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData( );

// get super tables of table marks
ResultSet rs = dm.getSuperTables( null , null, "marks" );
while( rs.next( ) ) {

   System.out.println(String.format("Table Catalog %s", rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") );
   System.out.println(String.format("Table Schema %s", rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM") );
   System.out.println(String.format("Table Name %s", rs.getString("TABLE_NAME") );
   System.out.println(String.format("Table Name %s", rs.getString("SUPERTABLE_NAME") );
}
```

You can use thes informations to get additional informations about the referenced table
and the foreigen and referenced primary keys:

```
ResultSet rs = dm.getCrossReference( null , null , "student" , null , null , "marks" );
System.out.println(String.format("Exported Keys Info Table %s.", "marks"));
while( rs.next( ) ) {

   String pkey = rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
   String ptab = rs.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
   String fkey = rs.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");
   String ftab = rs.getString("FKTABLE_NAME");
   System.out.println("primary key table = " + ptab);
   System.out.println("primary key = " + pkey);
   System.out.println("foreign key table = " + ftab);
   System.out.println("foreign key = " + fkey);
}
```

And finally you can retrieve the information about the super table by

```
ResultSet rs = dm.getTables(null,null,"student" ,null);
System.out.println("Table name:");
while (rs.next()){
     String table = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
     System.out.println(table);
}
```

Comment: hi,i have update my question.have a look at that.When i try to use getSupertables it return nothing in resultset.The resultset.next() return false.

Comment: The getSuperTables is implemented as a method that returns an empty ResultSet [com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData](http://www.java-frameworks.com/java/mysqlconnector/com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData.java.html). But you can use the `getImportedKeys`to retrieve a description of the primary key columns that are referenced by a table's foreign key columns. i.e. `getImportedKeys(null,null,"marks")` is expected to return at least the primary key info of the `student`table

Comment: super tables are a different concept: they refer to table inheritance structures, not to foreign key relations, as MySQL - afaik - does not have table inheritance, it will `getSuperTables` will return an empty resultset.